# Why Google Places API not showing all photos?

Tags: google-plus, google-places-api, google-places

When I do a request like [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?language=es&reference=CoQBcgAAAJWNopqy-5xWA6WtNWHozO--3v7Sse_nF5E9VE0FytQinAes2lDMPMi0hauGSPndajaAwq6AdTQnL9aIoNlRqGR3-RVMd-nvb5kTwmIlEbblmrzIOm7yblL8gc735lI1oWEK2CkfNvMHJCZ7tql5ezrliQtP2gyGRBYqhz1J9YWjEhDiIs0vvUqKg-5vi8MZqC4kGhS5vTKLBBfWPnKVL9M20ZHK-Zw4Xw&sensor=false&key=APIKEY) it show me 1 photo_reference but in the url of this site in Google + there are 12 [photos](https://plus.google.com/107942999701080489993/photos/photo/5959429115476120114?hl=es).

How I get all the photos from Google +?

Answer (score 0):

You have to request the "place/details" to get all the details about it.
something like this.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=Image_ref&key=YourKey

It's probably lat XD, it was asked two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#photo_references):

> Note: The number of photos returned varies by request.
>
> - A Find Place, Nearby Search, or Text Search request returns at most one photo element in the array.
> - A Place Details request returns up to ten photo elements.

It is unclear to me if you can get more than 10 photos.